# Rails 6 : NoMethodError and undefined method errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, export-to-csv, haml, ruby-on-rails-6, nomethoderror

I am trying to add a post action button to upload a CSV to get data from CSV into postGreSQL database. But getting the following error(copied the error from request response of chrome devtools)

```
NoMethodError in Admin::UnitsController#import

undefined method `content_type' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #15):

#13     file = params[:file]
#14     
*15     return redirect_to import_admin_tenant_site_units_path, notice: 'Only CSV please' unless file.content_type == "text/csv"
```

I have tried the following which is giving me the error.

Following the `routes.rb`

```
  namespace :admin do
    get '', to: 'dashboard#index', as: 'root'
    # resourceful routes 
    resources :oauth_clients
    resources :tenants do
      resources :sites do
        #resources :production_shifts
        resources :units do
          resources :log_data_fields, only: [:create, :index]
            # collection route 
            collection do 
              post :import #post action 
            end
          member do
            get :logs
            get :export_log
          end
          resources :reports
          resources :grafana_dashboards
          resources :data_adapters, except: [:show]
          get 'data_adapters/start'
        end
      end
      resources :users
      resources :login_activities
      # resources :login_activities
    end
  end
```

where post action "import" is of concern currently for this error.

I have included the import method's logic in the `units_controller.rb` as follows :

```
class Admin::UnitsController < Admin::BaseController

  # import request(this is gonna be a POST action)
  def import
    logger.debug("*****Testing the logger.*****")
    
    file = params[:file]
    
    return redirect_to import_admin_tenant_site_units_path, notice: 'Only CSV please' unless file.content_type == "text/csv"
    
    file = File.open(file)
    csv = CSV.parse(file, headers: true) 
    
    binding.b
    
    redirect_to import_admin_tenant_site_units_path, notice:"Imported tags !"
  end
```

More things are to be done and I cannot even show complete code in public due to restricted reasons.
My rails debugging gem `debug` doesnt work either means it doesnt gets invoked even after mentioning it there as `binding.b`. Earlier it was working few days back but I dont know what mistakes I did.
And Sorry for poor explaining language.

Here I am also showing the frontend view code of the part where the csv file gets uploaded from. `importtags.html.haml` :

```
%p{:style => "color: green"}= notice

= form_with model:@log_data_field, url: import_admin_tenant_site_units_path, method: :post do |form|

    - if @log_data_field.errors.any?
        #error_explanation
            %h2= "#{pluralize(@log_data_field.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this log_data_field from being saved:"
            %ul
            - @log_data_field.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
                %li= message

    = form.file_field :file, accept: ".csv"
    <br>
    <br>

    -#button.btn.primary{:type => "submit", data: { disable_with: "Please wait..."}}
    %button.btn.primary{:type => "submit"}
        -#= form.button "Import"
        = "Import"
```

PS : `-#` are indicating comments in the above haml code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`params[:file]` is `nil` so the local `file` variable is going to be `nil` as well.

In the rails log you can see the params hash usually after `Started POST` and `Processing by` lines like `Parameters: {...}`
But you can always just use `puts` inside the controller to debug like `p params` to see its content.

I bet the `file` key inside the `params` hash is going to be nested under the name of your model.

Try `file = params[:YOUR_MODEL_NAME][:file]`

Maybe `file = params[:log_data][:file]`?:D

Comment: Omg wow thankyou so much !! Made changes as you said in the import def line -> `file = params[:log_data_field][:file]` and it worked and also the debugging console got generated :D